# reactivemongo : How to println a TraversableBSONDocument content?

Tags: mongodb, scala, morphia

for debugging purpose I would like to see what a TraversableBSONDocument has inside, I'm not able to see the content of a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it ! :

```
val query = BSONDocument()
      .equal("userId", user.id.map(_.value).map(_.toLong).get)
      .greaterThanOrEqual("start", interval.start.jodaDateTime)
      .lesserThan("end", interval.end.jodaDateTime)
      .count("RREntity")

println(BSONDocument.pretty(query))
```